# I Install .NET Framework 4.7.2 but it gives me error?

Tags: .net

When I try to  install .NET Framework 4.7.2 downloaded from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks, I get the following error message:

> Blocking Issues:
>
> The .NET Framework 4.7.2 redistributable does not apply to this operating
> system. Please download the .NET Framework 4.7.2 for your operating system
> from the Microsoft Download Center.

My windows version is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Do you need sdk or?

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 32bit (x86) or 64bit (x64)? and Are you downloading the X86 or x64 installer?

Comment: Windows 10 should already have .NET 4.7.2 on it. Is there a reason you believe you need to install it?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 could mean a lot of things (sdk, runtime, bit version, etc.); you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Windows 10 1803 or newer**, then the .NET Framework 4.7.2 is already included as an OS component:

- [Mailbag: What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os)

The error message is misleading: There is no need to download it - it's already there!

Comment: My Windows Version is Windows 1903.

Can you please tell me version 4.7.2 installed on my pc which location because i didn't find in windows Features .

Comment: @PatelTejas: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. Don't mind that the version number in the path is not 4.7. Since all 4.x versions are in-place upgrades, they are all in the `v4.0.30319` directory.

Comment: can you please tell how to i use  4.7.2 from this location ? sorry for my miss understanding.

Comment: @PatelTejas: What exactly do you mean by "*use*"? It's there, and any .NET-4-based application that you run will use it automatically.